# Filtering array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to query a document that looks like -:

```
{
    fname : "Michael",
    fields: [
                {
                    field:"[A,B,C,D]"
                },
                {
                    field:"[A,C,D]"
                }
            ]
}
```

Now from this document I want the resultant to be :

```
    {
            fname : "Michael",
            fields: [
                        {
                            field:"[A,C,D]"
                        }
                    ]

    }
```

I am using this query to get the result, but I am getting error:-

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        $project : {
            _id : 0,
            fields : { $filter : { input : "$fields", as : "f", cond : {"$$f.field" : {$nin : [/B/]}}}}}
        }
    }
])
```

Can anyone help in resolving the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/) to check the existence of a single character (returns `-1` otherwise):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        fields : { 
            $filter : { 
                input : "$fields", 
                as : "f", 
                cond : { $eq: [ { "$indexOfBytes": [ "$$f.field", "B" ] }, -1 ] }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a2oTMOgYG5D)